# Currently, what solutions are available for SPLIT payments with PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I see that Adaptive Payments are deprecated. So, as a new user, I am not able to use that.

What are ways to have same thing as SPLIT payments? (which was available with adaptive payments). What is being currently used to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Split payments is supported in either [Express Checkout (using the Classic APIs)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/) or with [PayPal for Partners](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/partners/).